# How can i send an object values to post request function in angular 5+.?

Tags: angular

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="classForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <label for="">Select Class:</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select formControlName="infoo" class="form-control" *ngFor="let info of classinfo">
            <option [ngValue]="info">{{info.degree}}:{{info.semester}}({{info.section}})"{{info.session}}"</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info ">Proceed </button>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```js
classForm = this.fb.group(
    {
        infoo: ['']

    }
);

onSubmit()
{
    this._userService.sendClassToAttend(this.classForm.value);
    this._router.navigateByUrl('Teacher-homepage/classattendance');
    console.log(this.classForm.value);
}
```

[console.log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCIAE.png)

when I post request I have received empty data in the server. how I access object value like infoo.degree and send to the server properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this if you want to send a single value to the server, in case that you want to post the entire object the code you used should do the job.

```
 onSubmit()
  {
    this._userService.sendClassToAttend(this.classForm.value.infoo.degree);
     this._router.navigateByUrl('Teacher-homepage/classattendance');
    console.log(this.classForm.value);
  }
```

The method in service class is as below:

```
sendClassToAttend(student: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.url, student, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    }).pipe(catchError(this.handleerror));
  }
```

handleerror is a custom method that I have created for my application, you can ignore this part.

Comment: Thank you so much for your concern. but Still i am receiving empty values.

Comment: i use localStorage instead of passing in argument.Thank you, (this.classForm.value.infoo.degree) helps me to send data.